# Does Gnome Do work with Gnote?

Tags: tomboy, gnome-do, gnote

There's a great plugin for Gnome Do that searches tomboy notes really quickly. I can't imagine living without it. I want to switch to gnote, but I don't know whether it will work with Gnome Do. Is there a simple way to get them to work together?

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid not. The communication between Do and Tomboy is done over DBus using the hardcoded `org.gnome.Tomboy` interface. Gnote uses `org.gnome.Gnote`, so they will not be able to talk to each other. If they implement the same interface then it might not be too hard to patch the Do plugin to use either DBus interface though.

(but why would you use gnote over Tomboy unless you have a problem with Mono, which you clearly don't as you are using Do..?)